# ColdFusion file operation rejected with an exception error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm still using coldfusion 8 and the file operation I wrote works for one application but when I reuse the codes for another application I got an exception error.
I'm just simply need to copy, rename and move uploaded file from one directory to another.That's all I need. And this is for Oracle bcp from csv file.
All the permissions have been checked and allowed, all of the paths have been checked and correct. Both application reside at the same coldfusion server (unix based).

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I'm calling my comp:

```
    <CFSET DestinationLoc = "/space/users/www/data/temp/Archives/#Trim(session.usergroup)#/">
    <CFSET SourceLoc = "/space/users/www/data/temp/#Trim(session.usergroup)#">
    <CFSET FileName = "#Trim(CFFILE.ServerFile)#">

    <CFSET CopyRenameObjObj = createObject("component", "cfcomponents.ParentComp.Copy_and_Rename").init()>
    <CFSET CopyRenameObjObj.Copy_and_Rename(DestinationLoc,SourceLoc,FileName)>
```

I created a copy and rename cfc:

```
     <CFCOMPONENT>

       <CFFUNCTION name="Init" access="public" returntype="any" output="false" hint="Returns an initialized component instance.">
          <cfreturn THIS />
       </CFFUNCTION>

       <CFFUNCTION name="Copy_and_Rename">
         <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
         <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
         <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">

         <!--- First copy the file from source location to destination location --->
         <cffile action = "copy" destination = "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#"
                                source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#"/>

         <!--- Then move the file from the source to detination 2 --->
         <cffile action = "move" destination = "/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/bin/"
                                source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#"/>

         <cffile action = "rename" destination = "/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/bin/#Trim(session.usergroup)#_PARENTLOADFeed.txt"
                                  source = "/opt/coldfusion8/runtime/bin/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#"/>

       </CFFUNCTION>           

     </CFCOMPONENT>
```

The error I'm getting is:
Despite of this error, the directory is there, the file is renamed, moved successfully but the process stop due to this error!

> An exception occurred when performing a file operation copy on files 
>   /space/users/www/data/temp/BC/BC_Smallfile.TXT and
>   /space/users/www/data  /temp/Archives/BC/.
>
> The cause of this
>   exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /space
>   /users/www/data/temp/BC/BC_Smallfile.TXT (No such file or directory).
>
> The error occurred in /space/users/www/webdocsec/cfcomponents      /ParentComp/Copy_and_Rename.cfc: line 23

**Problem code:**

```
   <!--- Source     : /space/users/www/data/temp/BC/BC_testfile.TXT  --->
   <cffile action = "copy" destination =    
   "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#"
   source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#"/>
```

Comment: FileNotFoundException may be a bit of a misnomer. It can also mean a file is not accessible. For example, due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: *All the permissions have been checked and allowed, all of the paths have been checked* Exactly what tests did you perform to verify the permissions and file existence? So as not to overlook the obvious, since you are on unix did you check for case sensitivity as well?